# How to send a KeyValue list to Kafka?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to send a List[KeyValue] to the topic, in a Kafka Streams app. But the stream expects a single KeyValue. How I can send the KeyValues to the stream, instead of the whole list?

```
class MainTopology {

  val createTopology = (sourceTopic: String, sinkTopic: String) => {
    val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
    builder.stream(sourceTopic)
      .map[String, Option[JsonMessage]]((key, value) => toJsonEvent(key, value))
      .map[String, String]((key, value) => toFormattedEvents(key, value))
      .to(sinkTopic)
    builder.build()
  }

  private val toJsonEvent = (key: String, value: String) => {
    println(value)
    val jsonEventsAsCaseClasses = jsonToClass(value)
    new KeyValue(key, jsonEventsAsCaseClasses)
  }

  private val toFormattedEvents = (key: String, value: Option[JsonMessage]) => {
    val jsonEvents: List[String] = formatEvents(value)
    jsonEvents.map(event => new KeyValue(key,event))
  }

}
```

The second map is not compiling due to this.

`Expression of type List[KeyValue[String, String]] doesn't conform to expected type KeyValue[_ <: String, _ <: String]`

I update my code, but now it is throwing another error:

```
    val builder = new StreamsBuilder()
    builder.stream(sourceTopic)
      .map[String, Option[JsonMessage]]((key, value) => toJsonEvent(key, value))
      .flatMap(
      (key, value) => toFormattedEvents(key, value)
    )
      .to(sinkTopic)
    builder.build()
  }

  private val toJsonEvent = (key: String, value: String) => {
    println(value)
    val jsonEventsAsCaseClasses = jsonToClass(value)
    new KeyValue(key, jsonEventsAsCaseClasses)
  }

  private val toFormattedEvents = (key: String, value: Option[JsonMessage]) => {
    val jsonEvents: List[String] = formatEvents(value)
    jsonEvents.map(event => new KeyValue(key,event)).toIterable.asJava
  }
```

```
Error:(15, 8) inferred type arguments [?1,?0] do not conform to method flatMap's type parameter bounds [KR,VR]
      .flatMap(
Error:(16, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[String,Option[org.minsait.streams.model.JsonMessage],Iterable[org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[String,String]]]
 required: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: String, _ >: Option[org.minsait.streams.model.JsonMessage], _ <: Iterable[_ <: org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue[_ <: KR, _ <: VR]]]
      (key, value) => toFormattedEvents(key, value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `flatMap()` and `flatMapValues()` to replace the second `map()`.
https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html

For example:

```scala
.flatMap[String, Long]((key, value) => Seq(("foo", 1L), ("bar", 2L)))
```

If you do intent to keep using `map` for some reason, then see below.

> The second map is not compiling due to this.
>
> ```
> Expression of type List[KeyValue[String, String]] doesn't conform to expected type KeyValue[_ <: String, _ <: String]
> ```

The corresponding code, for reference:

```scala
.map[String, String]((key, value) => toFormattedEvents(key, value))
```

What you need is something like:

```scala
.map[String, List[KeyValue[KR, VR]]]((key, value) => toFormattedEvents(key, value))
```

where `KR` and `VR` are the key and value types, respectively, as returned by `toFormattedEvents()` (the actual return types are not clear from your question). For this to work you must also have `Serde` for the `List[KeyValue[KR, VR]]` type.

Let me illustrate this with a few different types so it's easier to understand which part of the method call refers to which type. Assume we want to the map output to have a key type of `Integer` and a value type of `List[KeyValue[String, Long]]`:

```scala
.map[Integer, List[KeyValue[String, Long]]]((key, value) => (5, List(KeyValue.pair("foo", 1L), KeyValue.pair("bar", 2L))))
```

Note that this example assigns the same values to every mapped record, but it's not the point of the example.

Comment: I am trying to achieve it with those functions but I can not do it.

Comment: I see, so if I want to use flatMap, I need to switch the second map for a flatMap?

Comment: Yes, that's what you'd need to do.

Comment: I updated the question, I can't make it work. Nevermind, already solved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer with a `flatMap` example. For instance, you forgot to add type information to `flatMap`.